# Why is 1 or 0 still a Prime number?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primzahl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean ergebnis = false; // Abfragen ob Ergebnis wahr oder falsch
        int i;
        int n; // Variablen deklarieren
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner aufrufen

        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die erste zu untersuchende Zahl ein: \n");

        n = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" \nEs wird nun überprüft, ob die Zahl " + n + " eine Primzahl ist: \n");

        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) { // Zählvariable; Bedingung; Schrittweite
            if ((n % i) == 0) // Wenn n mod 2 = 0
            {
                ergebnis = true;

            }
        }

        if (ergebnis == false) {
            System.out.println("Die eingegebene Zahl ist eine Primzahl");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Die eingegebene Zahl ist keine Primzahl");
        }

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

I try to write a code which is checking if its a prime number or not. But I don't get the logic.

Question: Why is 0 or 1 still a prime number and how can i fix that?

Comment: Because you start the loop at 2 and the only condition for the number not to count as a prime is if you find a divisor _greater or equal than 2_ in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code will only mark a number as "not prime", i.e. `ergebnis = true` is if you find a divisor that's equal or greater than two. Obviously, neither `0` nor `1` has such a divisor.

So just add an extra check whether the number is smaller than two:

```
if (n < 2) {
    ergebnis = true; // meaning 'not prime'
}
```

(By the way: terrible choice of variable name. Does `ergebnis` (German for "result") mean that the result is "it's prime" or "not a prime"?)

Also, you could improve your comments: instead of just repeating what the code does, explain why it does it and what it means. E.g., instead of

```
if((n%i)==0) //Wenn n mod 2 = 0
```

how about

```
if((n%i)==0) //divisor found -> not a prime
```

Comment: Thank you again. I do the comments like this to understand the code right. It is just for myself.. You know its way easier to read german instead of java :D

Answer (score 0):

Add `n>1` condition.

Then it will give the right result for **0**,**1** and **negative numbers** too!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Primzahl {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    boolean ergebnis=false; //Abfragen ob Ergebnis wahr oder falsch
    int i;
    int n; //Variablen deklarieren
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner aufrufen 

    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die erste zu untersuchende Zahl ein: \n");

    n=scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println(" \nEs wird nun überprüft, ob die Zahl " + n + " eine Primzahl ist: \n" );



    for (i=2;i<n;i++){ //Zählvariable; Bedingung; Schrittweite
        if((n%i)==0) //Wenn n mod 2 = 0 
        {
            ergebnis=true; 

        }}

    if (ergebnis==false && n>1)
    {
    System.out.println("Die eingegebene Zahl ist eine Primzahl");
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Die eingegebene Zahl ist keine Primzahl");
        }

    scanner.close();

}}
```